# Listview Ui won't update while applying filter /search

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a listview to which am applying a filter , the filter works but the UI won't update the list is unchanged .
this is my implementation

```
class QrqcOnlineListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _QrqcOfflineListViewState createState() => _QrqcOfflineListViewState();
}

List<Qrqc> filteredQrqc = [];

List<Qrqc>? qrqcList = [];

class _QrqcOfflineListViewState extends State<QrqcOnlineListView> {
  List<Qrqc>? myList;
  String? label;

  Future<List<Qrqc>?> getQrqcData() => SharedPreferenceMyQrqc().getListQrqc();
  List<Qrqc> filteredQrqc = [];
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  String? _searchText;

  List<TypeSettings> listTypes = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    Provider.of<MyQrqcListViewModel>(context, listen: false).fetchMyQrqc();
    super.initState();

    fetchTypes();
  }

  fetchTypes() async {
    listTypes = (await SettingsViewModel().fetchTypes());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var myQrqcListViewModel = Provider.of<MyQrqcListViewModel>(context);
    myList = myQrqcListViewModel.articlesList;
    List<Qrqc>? qrqcList = myList;
    filteredQrqc = myList!;

    List<Qrqc> listFilter = List.from(qrqcList!);

    QrqcDetails? result;
    String? type;
    void updateList(String value) {
      setState(() {
        listFilter = qrqcList
            .where((element) =>
                element.title!.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase()))
            .toList();
      });
    }

    String? setTypeLabel() {
      for (int j = 0; j < listFilter.length; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listTypes.length; i++) {
          if (listTypes[i].id == listFilter[j].typeID) {
            listFilter[j].typeName = listTypes[i].label;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: "Search",
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(4.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          onChanged: (value) => updateList(value),
        ),
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: ListView.builder(
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: listFilter.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                String? backgroundImage;

                String? _setImage() {
                  setTypeLabel();
                  if (listFilter[index].typeName == "Delivery") {
                    backgroundImage = "assets/icons/icon_delivery.png";
                  } else if (listFilter[index].typeName == "Security") {
                    backgroundImage = "assets/icons/icon_security.png";
                  } else if (listFilter[index].typeName == "Quality") {
                    backgroundImage = "assets/icons/quality.png";
                  } else if (listFilter[index].typeName == "Cost") {
                    backgroundImage = "assets/icons/Cost.png";
                  } else if (listFilter[index].typeName == "People") {
                    backgroundImage = "assets/icons/people.png";
                  } else {
                    backgroundImage = "assets/icons/unknown.png";
                  }

                  // print("list types: $qrqcList[index].typeName");
                  //  print("_mTitle: $backgroundImage");
                  return backgroundImage;
                }

                return Column(
                  children: [
                    QrqcBody(
                      child: QrqcCard(
                          child: QrqcCardBody(
                        color: Colors.orange,
                        text: listFilter[index].status,
                        leading: QrqcCardLeaing(imgPath: _setImage()),
                        trailing: QrqcCardtrailing(
                          text: listFilter[index].progress.toString(),
                          percent: listFilter[index].progress.toString(),
                        ),
                        title: listFilter[index].id.toString(),
                        subtitle: listFilter[index].title,
                        chlidren: [
                          QrqcDetailsCardFirstRow(
                            product: listFilter[index].productName ?? 'inconnu',
                            role: listFilter[index].role ?? "inconnu",
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 10),
                          QrqcDetailsCardSecondRow(
                            perim: listFilter[index].perimeterName ?? "inconnu",
                            date: convertDateTimeDisplay(
                                listFilter[index].createdAt!),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 10),
                        ],
                      )),
                    ),
                 
                  ],
                );
              }),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I don't know what's wrong especially that the filter is working and i got no errors only the keyboard events in the stack trace  , if anyone can help i'd be grateful , i've been stuck for a while now

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your list is being re-initialized / reset every time in the **build** method; while you're filter the list correctly inside the **setState**, when the **build** method re-executes upon calling **setState**, you're  resetting it again when you do this:

```dart
// upon every rebuild, the listFilter gets reset to the original value
List<Qrqc> listFilter = List.from(qrqcList!);
```

What you could is:

- Use the existing property called ** _searchText** and store the value being provided as input by the **TextField** widget, that when it's empty, then you fetch the whole list, otherwise skip that logic, that way your **listFilter** remains filtered on the next widget rebuild, kind of like:

In your ***updateList** method:

```dart
void updateList(String value) {
      // store the value being provided as input to the filter
      // in the property called _searchText

      _searchText = value;
      setState(() {
        listFilter = qrqcList
          .where((element) =>
           element.title!.toLowerCase().contains(_searchText.toLowerCase()))
            .toList();
      });
    }
```

Inside the **build** method:

```dart
// check if its empty, that means there's no filter being applied

if (_searchText.isEmpty) {
   List<Qrqc> listFilter = List.from(qrqcList!);
}
```